# What is the process of using Dubai's Smart Gate for a foreign, non-resident first-timer?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, dxb

Swedish passport holders (even non-residents of the UAE nowadays) are among those that can use the Smart gate in Dubai. However, I've read that there's some eye scan first-timers have to go through.

What is the step.by step procedure, from getting into the immigration concourse to reaching baggage claim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did this last fall, and will share my experience, though I can't promise it hasn't changed.

When you reach the immigration area at Dubai's T3, there is a separate line for Smart Gate registration. The process is essentially the same as any immigration control: hand over your passport, answer any questions the officer might have about your trip, wait a moment while they scan your passport and check the computer. You'll then be asked to look straight ahead while a camera captures your biometrics. The officer will tap a few more keys on their keyboard, and you're all enrolled. The registration process is [described](http://www.emirates247.com/news/emirates/clear-uae-immigration-in-just-27-seconds-2016-04-13-1.626958) as taking "around 20 seconds." Once you're done, you just walk past the counter to the hand baggage x-ray required for all arrivals in Dubai, then to the baggage claim.

In short, it's just the normal immigration process, with a brief additional biometric scan added.

Note that, when I was there, the Smart Gate registration counters had a line, while the normal immigration counters did not. I ended up wasting a bunch of time registering for a time-saving service I am unlikely to get much use out of, but your mileage may vary.